# TypeError: document.getElementbyId is not a function

Tags: javascript, html

In the following snippet everything works as expected, but when I click "Show Source" Firefox produces this error:

```
--
[11:07:30.630] TypeError: document.getElementbyId is not a function @ http://localhost:8888/html5/native-rich-text.html:10
```

And Safari produces a similar error. What is causing this?

```js
function showSource() {
  var content = document.getElementbyId("edit").innerHTML
  content.replace(/</g, '&lt;');
  content.replace(/>/, '&gt: ');
  prompt("Your Code:", content);

}

function createLink() {
  var url = prompt("Enter URL:", "http://");
  if (url)
    document.execCommand("createlink", false, url);
}
```

```html
<h1>Native Rich Text</h1>
<p>No textboxes here, that's a &lt;div&gt; element!</p>
<div>
  <input type="button" value="Bold" onclick="document.execCommand('bold', false, null);">
  <input type="button" value="Italic" onclick="document.execCommand('italic', false, null);">
  <input type="button" value="Underline" onclick="document.execCommand('underline', false, null);">
  <input type="button" value="Add Link" onclick="createLink();">
  <input type="button" value="Show Source" onclick="showSource();">
</div>
<div id="edit" style="border:solid black; height: 300px; width: 400px;" contenteditable="true">
  Hello!
</div>
```

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Case sensitive: `document.getElementById` (notice the capital `B`).

Comment: even though it's closed as too localized, it turns out that this question is helping me! thanks for this answer!

Comment: It helped me to! Thanks!

Comment: Five years later and that is the exact thing I did not capitalize. Thank you.

Comment: want to say this helped me too!

Comment: @ChenLiYong - Same applies to me.

Answer (score 19):

JavaScript is case-sensitive. The `b` in `getElementbyId` should be capitalized.

```
var content = document.getElementById("edit").innerHTML;
```

Comment: @jewishspiderweb ...Did you mean to comment on the original question instead of my answer? Otherwise, I'm not entirely sure what you mean.

Comment: I meant to say that your answer is a duplicate, I agree that it is clearer than the above answer, but still, you should edit his answer instead of posting a new one.
I'd recommend that you delete this answer and edit the above answer.

Comment: @jewishspiderweb It looks like I posted my answer at the same time as Zeta (down to the second, funnily enough). If I had noticed, I probably wouldn't have posted mine. But I don't think I should edit their answer and replace it with mine, I wouldn't want someone else to do that to one of my answers either.

Comment: I get it, but it's the same answer, you're not replacing it, you're only making it more clear.