# How to set video ID from user input

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

I would like to be able to set the video ID to be played from user input via an `<input type="text">` field.

My naive attempt looks like so

```
<!DOCTYPE html>                                                                                        
<html>                                                                                                 
  <body>                                                                                               
    <p>                                                                                                
      ID:<input type="text" id="ytvideoid">                                                            
      <button onclick="loadVideo()">Load</button>                                                      
    </p>                                                                                               

    <iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="640" height="390"</iframe>                           

    <script>                                                                                           
      function loadVideo() {                                                                           
        var ytplayer = document.getElementByID("ytplayer");                                            
        var videoid = document.getElementByID("ytvideoid").value;                                      

        ytplayer.cueVideoById({                                                                        
          videoId: videoid                                                                             
        });                                                                                            
        ytplayer.playVideo();                                                                          
      }                                                                                                
    </script>                                                                                          
  </body>                                                                                              
</html>
```

but the player widget remains blank after entering an ID and clicking "Load".

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

1. Define a function before using it. Simply move the `<script>` above the `<button>`
2. You have a [typo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14171212/typeerror-document-getelementbyid-is-not-a-function) twice `getElementById` has a lower case "d".

In the end it will look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>                                                                                        
<html>                                                                                                 
  <body>      

    <script>                                                                                           
      function loadVideo() {                                                                           
        var ytplayer = document.getElementById("ytplayer");                                            
        var videoid = document.getElementById("ytvideoid").value;                                      

        ytplayer.cueVideoById({                                                                        
          videoId: videoid                                                                             
        });                                                                                            
        ytplayer.playVideo();                                                                          
      }                                                                                                
    </script>                                                                                                      
    <p>                                                                                                
      ID:<input type="text" id="ytvideoid">                                                            
      <button onclick="loadVideo()">Load</button>                                                      
    </p>                                                                                               

    <iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="640" height="390"</iframe>                           

  </body>                                                                                              
</html>
```

I can't help you any further than that however, because your example doesn't work after these two things are fixed, as it doesn't contain all the code needed to make it work.